# Getting UUIDs in a CouchApp with active vhost

Tags: couchdb, vhosts, couchapp

I am looking for the right way for loading new UUIDs or accessing the _session object in a couchapp behind a vhost.

I have written a couchapp and everything workes well with the *normal* but ugly urls. So if i use http://example.cloudant.com/mydb/_design/myapp/index.html as address everything works as expected. If I use www.mycouchapp.com (`mycouchapp.com CNAME -> example.cloudant.com/mydb/_design/myapp/_rewrite`).
I cannot access any ressource in the top level of couchdb like `_session, _stats, or _uuid`

Because of the security limitations I cannot make a rewrite-rule like `"from":"_session", "to": "../../../_session"` because more than `"../../"` are not allowed.

Is there a way or workaround for this problem?

Comment: OK, so i think there is no way to do this. In the meantime i found this thread in the cloudant support forum http://support.cloudant.com/discussions/questions/29-no-subject and it seems that cloudant enabled this feature for every user. in plain couchdb i think there is still no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you should use CouchDB's URL Rewriting and Vhost possibilities:

http://blog.couchone.com/post/443028592/whats-new-in-apache-couchdb-0-11-part-one-nice-urls

HTH

Cheers

Andy

Comment: mmm, yes, thanks i should and i would use vhost and rewrites _but_ 

`Because of the security limitations I cannot make a rewrite-rule like "from":"_session", "to": "../../../_session" because more than "../../" are not allowed.`